# Rails active record not returning what i would expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Locations table with 4 locations in it. The schema is as follows:

```
create_table "locations", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "state"
    t.string   "zip"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end
```

I'm running this in an ajax call and it keeps returning `Location` in my puts line below.

```
@current_location = Location.where('lower(name) = ?', params[:id][1..-1].humanize.downcase)     
p "@current_location = #{@current_location}"
```

`params[:id][1..-1].humanize.downcase` interprets to `'brooklyn park'`

I'm not actually finding this query in the log file and when i copy and paste the active record into the rails console, it seems to work just fine.

Why does it keep returning `'Location'`?

Comment: You sure you're passing the location name parameter in with the name `id`?  This isn't an activerecord issue, because as you've pointed out the query works.  It's an issue of passing the correct parameter in. (Your javascript and controller logic.)

Comment: Yes. Even when i take that params stuff out and just put `'brooklyn park'` in there, it still sets @current_location to '`Location'`

Comment: @jvnill What do you mean?

Comment: you forgot `.first`. `Location.where('lower(name) = ?', params[:id][1..-1].humanize.downcase).first` if you only want to deal with 1 record. also make sure that `.to_s` is declared in your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@current_location = Location.where('lower(name) = ?', params[:id][1..-1].humanize.downcase)
```

With

```
@current_location = Location.where('lower(name) = ?', params[:id][1..-1].humanize.downcase).first
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why this works and why without .first, it was setting it to 'Location'?

Comment: without `.first` it is a collection, and with `.first` it is an a member of collection

Comment: Makes sense, but why would it set to 'Location'?

Comment: you can write `p "@current_location = #{@current_location.inspect}"` to get results.